# Element does not loose focus

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, hover, focus

Compare this - http://bootswatch.com/2/cerulean/ and this - http://bootswatch.com/cerulean/ (third bootstrap), when you in 3rd version click on "Download" at the top of the page and right at once then click it again and move pointer away from it - everything is OK, but if you try to do the same in 2nd version - you will see `focus` border on element and darker background, I have solved it by adding

```
.navbar .nav>li>a:focus {
background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
}

.navbar .nav>li>a:focus:hover {
background-color: #1684c2;
}

.dropdown-toggle {
outline: none !important; }
```

But I assume that it is not the best solution or may be not crossbrowser - that is my question.

Answer (score 1):

Setting an !important tag on an element is not usually considered best practice, but if you use the implement the outline property on your a element that should work as in:

a:focus {outline: 0px none;}